# Building a Eclipse project using ANT build scripts

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ant

I am editing the question to make it more specific.
I want to run my application on some other machine which doesn't have an IDE like me.I want to deploy it on a container(Tomcat) on the other machine.  **How can I make sure that the dependencies are maintained?**

I have the **jars** in the lib folder,but about the other build targets I am not sure.
Also,I want to check in the project to **SVN** (So,that others can check out and deploy it ).

Comment: please familiarize yourself with ant yourself and ask specific questions here (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). This question is too broad to answer generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this,but not sure if in all the right way.The dynamic web project in eclipse creates its own directory structure for example **WebContent->WEB-INF->web.xml** and so on.But,when deploying on tomcat directly we need the WEB-INF in the root of the application.I had to make these changes and add a **build.xml** file to the root of the application for compiling my classes.The build was successful and I can run the app independently of eclipse.

Any comments would be helpful.